# auth0 - email verification - user account does not exist or verification code is invalid

Tags: auth0, email-verification

Here is my problem : In auth0 dashboard, I select a user within my users list and  click on send a verification email... The user receive the mail, click on the link and get an error "User account doesn't exist or verification code is invalid" But the user exists and I do not use passwordless or sms authentication , my users have to enter their password and are also stored in mongodb. Any ideas to solve this?

-- edited precision added --

@Arcseldon
I'am actually using a customDB and here is my getUser script, but I don't know what to change, could you help me?
Thank you!

```html
function getByEmail (email, callback) {

  mongo('mongodb://user:pass@dsXXXX.mlab.com:XXXX/base', function (db) {
    var users = db.collection('user');
    users.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {

      if (err) return callback(new Error("my error message"));
      if (!user) return callback(null);

var profile = {
    user_id:     user._id,
    nickname:    user.username,
    email:        user.email,
  };
  callback(null, profile);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Raise a support ticket with Auth0. Btw, do you get that behaviour with only a subset of your users, or is it the same error for any user you try to send a verification email for?

Comment: Hi Arcseldon, I have contacted Auth0, I'm waiting for their answer.. It is the same with all my users (those created from authentication api call (signup) as well as those created from auth.lock signup).

Comment: @cedric123 Did you get the problem "User account does not exist or the verification code is invalid." reolved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just re-read your question - where you state "my users have to enter their password and are also stored in mongodb." - are you referring to your own Mongo DB?  Are you using an Auth0 Custom DB Connection?  Confusingly, Auth0 also uses MongoDB for its own DB storage, hence the clarification. If you are using a Custom DB connection to your own DB, then this may be a misconfiguration of one of your Custom DB Scripts. If using Custom DB Script, please double-check the implementation of your `GetUser.js` script.

In the event, you are using an Auth0 DB (not a custom DB) then definitely check with Auth0 support team (as per comment and your reply above).